# Injective and Bijective functions

Tags: functions

1. Suppose that **$f: A→B$** and **$g:B→C$** are functions such that **$g◦f$** is *injective*. **Prove** that **$f$** must be *injective.*
2. Construct a *bijective* function $f:R→ (R\setminus \{0\})$.  **Prove** that your function is actually a *bijective* function.

Can someone help me on how do I prove it?

Comment: For two, try the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&x\notin\mathbb N\cup\{0\}\\x+1&x\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a value $f(x) = f(y) \in B$, since $g$ is a function,

$$g(f(x)) = g(f(y).$$

By the definition of injection of $g\circ f$, $x=y$.

So we have proven that
$$f(x)=f(y) \implies x = y,$$

i.e. $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose f is not invective.

There exists some $x,y$ in $A$ such that $f(x)= f(y)$

It which case $(g\circ f)(x) = (g\circ f)(y)$